# Подогнать размер прямоугольника по размерам текста

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-ui

## Описание

Есть у меня текст. Размер текста не стабилен, то есть у него может быть строк 10, 15 или другое количество. Вот например в изображении снизу, у объекта высота 200 и текст не помещается в нём.

[image]

---

## Вопрос

*Собственно каким образом подогнать высоту объекта чтобы текст был полностью виден?*

---

## Уточнение

Про опцию `Best Fit` знаю, не надо её тут использовать.

Comment: А про vertical overflow знаем?

Comment: @Yaroslav знаем. Тогда текст выходит за пределы объекта. Это не то что мне нужно.

Comment: Тебе нужно скриптом rect поменять?

Comment: @Yaroslav любым способом

Comment: В правом верхнем углу инспектора, рядом с замком есть выподающее меню. Переключи инспектор с normal на debag и увидешь в инспекторе текста много инфы о размерностях вбитого теаста и умещается ли он. Ко всем этим переменным можно обращаться в скрипте. На их основе можно будет подогнать размеры rect.

Comment: @Yaroslav хорошо, этот часть понятно, но я никак не могу получить высоту именно текста и даже если удалить весь текст или добавить новый, в инспекторе кроме строкового поля `Text` ничего не меняется.

Comment: Best fit работает наоборот: он пытается изменить размер контента, чтобы полностью заполнить прямоугольник.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker честно сказать я про это знаю, но я думал будут предлагать это решение со словами "А  вам этот вариант чем не угодил". Поэтому чтобы избежать лишних вопросов я уточнил этот часть :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно использовать компонент [Content Size Fitter](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/script-ContentSizeFitter.html). Поскольку речь идет про сам объект, а не про layout, то в настройках нужно использовать `Preferred`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Направление, куда будет увеличиваться прямоугольник, зависит от pivot'а.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]